# X11 window freezes if not touched for a few seconds

Tags: keyboard, mouse, x11, freeze

We have a custom built X11 app for running simulations.

The problem is if the window sits without any form of input, the window freezes. We found that the mouse input is hanging in the event dispatch. It appears to be an input lock.

1. Is there a way to fix this?
2. Since, normally we do not interact with the window, is there a way to turn off input (mouse and keyboard) without hanging (input lock)?

Comment: Going to need to see some code to be able to help you out.

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, it is a problem you will have to solve with the code.

Comment: It hangs in XNextEvent()            while(1)
    {
fprintf(stderr, "!!!%s:%d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        XNextEvent(gpDisplay, &tEvent);
fprintf(stderr, "!!!%s:%d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);

Comment: I tried a simple window program, but it worked fine.

Comment: More detail. I check it by moving the mouse over the window.